# CDH HDFS node decommission never ends

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera-cdh, fsck

We have a 12 servers hadoop cluster(CDH), Recent, we want to decommission three of them, but this process already been running there more than 2 days. But it never ends, Especially, in the past 24 hours, I saw there are only 94G data available on the three data-node, but the size seems not changing in the past 24 hours. even through the under replicated blocks number already been zero. The replication factor is 3 for all the data in hdfs.

**Below is the result for hadoop fsck command:**

Total size:    5789534135468 B (Total open files size: 94222879072 B)
Total dirs:    42458
Total files:   5494378
Total symlinks:        0 (Files currently being written: 133)
Total blocks (validated):  5506578 (avg. block size 1051385 B) (Total open file blocks (not validated): 822)
Minimally replicated blocks:   5506578 (100.0 %)
Over-replicated blocks:    0 (0.0 %)
**Under-replicated blocks: 0 (0.0 %)**
Mis-replicated blocks:     0 (0.0 %)
Default replication factor:    3
Average block replication: 2.999584
Corrupt blocks:        0
Missing replicas:      0 (0.0 %)
Number of data-nodes:      13
Number of racks:       1
FSCK ended at Mon Oct 17 16:36:09 KST 2016 in 781094 milliseconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to stop cloudera agent on the datanode.

`sudo service cloudera-scm-agent hard_stop_confirmed`

After the agent is stopped, you can just delete that datanode from hdfs instance page

Hope this works